# how to pass java string to webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, file

i'm making a android code editor and i embeded ace editor in my project using webview.
and now i want to read a file and setValue to editor here is my code

```js
try{
  Scanner obj = new Scanner(new File(/*a file path*/));
  String txt = "";
  while (obj.hasNextLine()){
    txt = txt.concat(obj.nextLine());
  }
  editor.loadUrl("javascript: aceeditor.setValue('"+txt+"');");
}
 catch (FileNotFoundException err){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, err.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

it's passing the txt value but file contents also contain symbols ` ' "
so it's throw a error
how to pass it?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace:

```
editor.loadUrl("javascript: senddata('"+txt+"', '"+ext+"');");
```

to

```
editor.loadUrl(String.format("http://%s.%s", txt, ext));
```

Comment: hey i want to load a file in my editor not url